# How to declare an Object return type in a WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm struggling with understanding how to define a WSDL that allows for returning a generic type Object that can be cast on the client to the real object. For example, I have a single return type Object for 4 different method calls. The 4 different methods have different parameter Objects when called. (e.g. CreatePerson(Person), CreateAnimal(Animal), etc...) Each one returns a ResultObject has a "Object" property that would contain the operated on object parameter. (e.g. CreatePerson(Person) would return ResultObject.Object = Person, the returned Person object would have updated properties, like ID, some timestamp, etc...)

Should I just have a Result object for each object? (e.g. ResultPerson = CreatePerson(), ResultAnimal = CreateAnimal(), etc...)

I have to layout the API before coding so thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just have a `Result` object for each object? (e.g. `ResultPerson = CreatePerson()`, `ResultAnimal = CreateAnimal()`, etc...)

Absolutely! There is nothing more irritating than a strongly-typed language that must deal with an API returning a generic `Object`. You get almost no benefit for the price of making your API **really** hard to use.

Don't be upset about the proliferation of classes. After all they are created by some tool like `wsdl2`-something (e.g. `wsdl2java`). If all your results have some common properties, consider having one abstract base type (e.g. `Animal`) and extend. That will make your API even better.